# How to insert data into an input field

Tags: angular

I can't figure out how to insert a value into the input field. Please show me how to do it?

`<input type="text" formControlName="emailAddress">`

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you need to do

Comment: I want to insert data into a field. I want that when the page opens, data is automatically inserted into this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "value" attribute in your input

```
<input type="email" formControlName="emailAddress" value="text-here"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add initial value where your from control is declare see below code:

```
emailAddress = new FormControl('Value Here');
```

see link for more details

[Add initial value in form control](https://gist.github.com/satish-birhade/d2af648d3ad47f97b373534ba74f9b86)

Comment: Link does not work

Comment: Can you please check now.

Answer (score 0):

To save a value you can use local storage

```
saveEmail(): void {
    localStorage.setItem('emailAddress', this.emailAddress);
    console.log('it is saved: ', this.emailAddress);
}
```

To get the data you can use ngOnInit event

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.emailAddress = localStorage.getItem('emailAddress');
    console.log('ths is read: ', this.emailAddress);
  }
```

To link input control with a var use [(ngModel)]="emailAddress", and you have to import FormsModule in order to it works

Here is a Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vnrgpv?file=src/main.ts

Comment: This method is not suitable